# How to retrieve/"Select" Date Using Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have the following Query string:

```
=QUERY(Scores!$A$3:$E, "SELECT A, min(D) WHERE (C = 'X30' AND B = 'East Palm') GROUP BY A ORDER BY min(D) ASC LIMIT 5 LABEL min(D) ''",0)
```

And would also like to retrieve the date from the data (Column E). I tried:

```
=QUERY(Scores!$A$3:$E, "SELECT A, E min(D)...
```

but it did not work and I received the following message:

> Error Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered ".

I have attached the Form link.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M5T-stwFQmPFqVDfxKH3Jh46JcQPauvCl5fV4opmgMQ/edit#gid=2146752760

Answer (score 0):

if you want dates you also need to include it under `group by` like:

```
=QUERY(Scores!$A$3:$E, 
 "select A,E,min(D) 
  where C = 'X30' 
    and B = 'East Palm' 
  group by A,E 
  order by min(D) asc 
  limit 5 
  label min(D) ''", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a simple syntax error in the line presented where you added `E`

```
=QUERY(Scores!$A$3:$E, "SELECT A, E min(D)...
```

Should be

```
=QUERY(Scores!$A$3:$E, "SELECT A, E, min(D)...
```

Notice the comma after `E`. We all make these types of errors.

However, that doesn't seem to be an issue in the gSheet as I see this is correct in the queries there.